# is there a way to download specific version of pypi package?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I would like to download specific setuptools version ( 57.4.0 ) - this is one time activity. After I download the file, I will keep it in a directory ( $PYPKG_DIR ) and install in a virtual environment using the below command whenever required

`$virtual_env_dir/bin/python/ -m pip install --no-index --find-links $PYPKG_DIR --requirement=$REQUIREMENTS_TXT_FILE`

Currently, I am able to locate [setuptools-60.9.0.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/d3/e85cd0d84cf52054caed83b64dd8c922bbf0e33071689d7e3da3f96caabd/setuptools-60.9.0.tar.gz) ( Download link ) from pypi.org, please let me know how can I get the specific version of setuptools source file ?

Answer (score 2):

You can by specifying the version using the syntax below:

```sh
# Replace 57.4.0 with the desired version #
pip install -Iv setuptools==57.4.0
```

If you are interested with the actual files, you could go to the download files tab of the PyPi package.

[image]

**CREDITS & UPDATES to phd and his comment below**

or you can download it using the command below:

```sh
pip download setuptools==57.4.0
```

Comment: I would wanna download the file only, would install it later from a directory where I would copy the file into.

Comment: `pip download setuptools==57.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

You go to the History page :

https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#history

Then here:

https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/57.4.0/

And click on Download

[image]